# Rails 3 override Devise sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I need to override Devise sessions controller during the login process (Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, Devise 1.3.4), I tried this without any effect

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    resource = build_resource
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope :new }
  end

end
```

Ideas?

**EDIT**
As indicated in the answer, I also need to change the route. In addition, I also need to copy the views. It's better explained here
http://presentations.royvandewater.com/authentication-with-devise.html#8

My custom strategy:

```
devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.strategies.add(:custom_strategy) do
    def authenticate!
      ... authenticate against 3rd party API...
      if res.body =~ /success/
        u = User.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:user][:email])
        if u.new_record?
          u.save
        end
      success!(u)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you altered your route to use your new controller?

```
/config/routes.rb

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

Comment: Yes I just figured that out too and I also need to copy the views it seems. Do I keep the original `devise_for :users` route in addition to the above change? I don't wish to override the other actions.

Comment: There is another problem with this, it also doesn't execute the default database authentication strategy in addition to the custom strategy I add, not sure how to fix this.

Comment: There should only be 1 `devise_for`, and after you copy the views it should work even with the actions you didn't override. 
As for your other issue, I'm not completely following. Do you have the `:database_authenticatable` option set in your model. (i.e. devise :database_authenticatable)

Comment: Yes `:database_authenticable` has always been there for `User`. I also have a custom strategy in addition, see edited question for details.

Comment: My custom strategy still executes but it no longer falls through to `:database_authenticable` if it fails to authenticate