# Devise : /login with param giving `undefined method stringify_keys`

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

For `/login` my application is working fine, but for `/login?user="something"` `giving 500`

I am using devise gem

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'devise/sessions'}, :skip => [:sessions]   do
  get '/login' => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
end
```

error :

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 263ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "\"something\"":String):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.6ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (7.9ms)
```

Comment: Have you tried the query string without the quotes? e.g. `/login?user=something`

Comment: Yes getting same error for `/login?user=something` also

Comment: to solve this i have overwrite devise session controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringify_keys` is a method that Rails mixes into the Ruby Hash class, so the problem here is that devise is expecting a hash of attribute-value pairs in the user param instead of a plain string. In other words its expecting a User model object rather than just a user name.

The convention that Rails uses for packing nested attribute value pairs into URL query string or HTML form params uses square brackets, so you probably need something like this:

```
/login?user[name]=someone&user[password]=secret
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve, But how can I handle this exception, so user could not get 500 message.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen in response to `/login?user=something`? As far as Devise is concerned its invalid input and its just not designed to handle it. If you want to change its behaviour then you can override the Devise SessionsController and implement whatever parameter handling you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070320/rails-3-override-devise-sessions-controller